# Can I remove relative pronoun and keep the punctuation?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Is it ok to remove "**whom**" in the following sentence?

> He finally met Paul, whom he had always admired.

I personally believe that if I remove *both comma and pronoun* it would be correct:

> He finally met Paul he had always admired.

But this one does not make sense. I don't know why, but it seems wrong:

> He finally met Paul, he had always admired.

Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot do that.  The relative is required to introduce the subordinate clause.

You can say this:

> He finally met the man he had always admired.
>
> He finally met Paul, the man he had always admired.

And if we concoct a scenario where there were several Pauls with the same surname, and he went to a book-signing, say, thinking to meet the author he admired but it turned out to be a different Paul, so that he would not meet "his" Paul for several more years, you could say:

> He finally met *the* Paul he had always admired.